# Input desabilitado não passa para o $_POST

Tags: php, input

Esse são meus dois inputs:

```
<div class="span3">
<label for="cor11">CROMIA<span class="required"></span></label>
<select class="span12" name="cor11" id="cor11" onchange="validarForm()" value="">
<option <?php if($result->cor11 == 'Selecione a Cor'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="Selecione a Cor">Selecione a Cor</option>
<option <?php if($result->cor11 == '-'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="-">-</option>
<option <?php if($result->cor11 == 'CYAN'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="CYAN">CYAN</option>
<option <?php if($result->cor11 == 'MAGENTA'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="MAGENTA">MAGENTA</option>
<option <?php if($result->cor11 == 'YELLOW'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
<option <?php if($result->cor11 == 'BLACK'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="span3">
     <label for="cor12">COR ESPECIAL/PANTONE</label>
     <input id="cor12" disabled class="span12" type="text" name="cor12" style="text-transform:uppercase" value="<?php echo $result->cor12 ?>" />
</div>
```

O *input* `cor12` é desabilitada mediante escolha feita no input `cor11`.

Se a escolha na `cor11` for "-", habilita o *input* da `cor12`. Script abaixo:

```
function validarForm() { 
       var optionSelect = document.getElementById("cor11").value;

       if(optionSelect =="-" ){ 
           document.getElementById("cor12").disabled = false;
       }else{
           document.getElementById("cor12").disabled = true;
       }
}
```

Quando faço uma edição, ele até executa o `POST` e salva no BD.

Porém, se eu voltar na edição, e fazer uma alteração em qualquer campo, a informação destes dois *inputs* é apagada do BD.

O que acontece ?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o atributo `readonly` ao invés do `disabled`.

Comment: Testei, mas não rola, porque se eu precisar alterar(editar) novamente, não consigo.

Comment: A idéia é se no campo cor12 <> empty, permace com o conteúdo e não apagar.